# Syncing an excel sheet from a PC to Google Drive every minute

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm working on a real time energy monitoring project.
I have a program written in Visual Basic which fetches readings from the energy meters and logs the readings in an excel sheet every minute.

I want to sync this file to `Google Drive` every minute as the excel sheet on my PC gets updated every minute. I will then embed this `Google Drive` excel sheet onto a web page.

Please guide me in simple manner or provide me some resources to do so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any research on connecting/uploading to GoogleDrive via VBA?